# IIS 7 ISAPI Handler Mapping Caching

Tags: iis, caching, dll, iis-7, isapi

I have a question for ISAPI Handler Mapping in IIS 7.

I added a Mapping and i would like to know, how i can configure the Server to cache the whole thing.

My web.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="ISAPI-dll" />
            <add name="Orgmanager Search Handler Dir De" path="orgmanager.dll" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\inetpub\wwwroot\orgmanager\dir_de\orgmanager.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Execute" preCondition="bitness32" />
        </handlers>
        <caching>
            <profiles>
                <add extension=".dll" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
                <add extension=".html" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
                <add extension=".pl" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
            </profiles>
        </caching>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Is this cached by the Server?
If no, how do i configure the whole thing to get cached?

Thanks and Greetings:
Spinne

Answer (score 0):

Use a wildcard for the extension?

```
<add extension="*" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
```